# lvremove without root user privileges?

Tags: permissions, lvm

I am working on a backup script which creates LVM snapshots. After creating the snapshot it will be compressed via lz4 and afterwards the script is supposed to delete the snapshot out of the VG.

Deleting the snapshot failes due to missing privileges. I would rather avoid to run this script as root. Is there any other possibility to let the script create AND remove the snapshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with `sudo`. Just assign appropriate permissions to the backup user. `sudo` is quite flexible and you can limit what the user is allowed to do down to very specific commands.

See `man sudo` and `man sudoers`

Comment: would sudo also work via cron? If I understand you right, you would assign the right to delete the LVM right to a user e.g. "backup_user". Would this not be a security risk, as this user also would be able to delete all other LVMS, not just the snapshots?

Comment: Yes, you can also do this from cron with some caveats (e.g. you need to allow access without password). As for the security risk, I usually solve this by allowing `sudo` access to a shell script that does exactly what I allow and nothing more. Create a special user that can't login, give him sudo rights for your backup script only (without password) and define a cron job for him that does the backup.

Comment: You can also specify arguments to a command in sudoers, and sudo will not allow anything else.

Comment: OK, thank you. This sounds like a duable procedure.